# How do I alphabetically sort a generic List(Of String) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

I've created and populated a generic list of strings like this:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of String)
MyList.Add("Beta")
MyList.Add("Echo")
MyList.Add("Charlie")
MyList.Add("Alpha")
MyList.Add("Delta")
```

Now I want to order it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
MyList.Sort()
```

Comment: Probably not? Alphabetical sorting is not really the same as String sorting. You'd sort the (correct order) list of ("aa", "Ab", "a'c") as ("Ab", "a'c", "aa"). Text sorting should always consider Language, and Collation level (Do you consider "e" and "ë" the same or not?)